# Can I pass parameter attributes through a function?

Tags: c#, logging

Weird and very specific question. Right now we have a logging interface that uses the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` like so:

```
interface ILogger
{
    void Info(string message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "");
}
```

Which is all great and perfect and works fine in our implementation. However, a requirement has come up that we need to write some functions that can be invoked in our process and also elsewhere, and that these functions need to use a defined `ITracer` class that looks like the following:

```
interface ITracer
{
    void TraceInformation(string message);
}
```

So when run in our environment, these functions should log to our current logging infra, but when run in the other environment, it has it's own `ITracer` set that does its own thing. So I wrote a shim that just passes the messages through when called in our environment:

```
class Logger : ILogger
{
    public void Info(string message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "") => // log some stuff

    public ITracer GetTraceWriter() => return new TraceWriter(this);
}

class TraceWriter : ITracer
{
    public TraceWriter(ILogger logger) => this.logger = logger;

    public void TraceInformation(string message) => this.logger.Info($"{message}");
}
```

This works fine, but the `memberName` is part of the log message that is output, and with this implementation, when the TraceWriter starts logging, it always has the `memberName` equal to `TraceInformation`. Is there a way I can pass this parameter attribute through the function call somehow? The main issue here is that I cannot change the `ITracer` interface.

Solutions thought of but can't get to work:

- Change the `TraceInformation` call in `ITracer` to return a function call to `ILogger.Info` that could be invoked directly from the method (Cannot do this because I cannot change the ITracer interface)

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do, which may or may not be ideal, would be to use the [`StackFrame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe(v=vs.110).aspx) class to look up the stack to the calling function.

You can use this to iterate through the stack to either find (or exclude) specific types, or perhaps types that implement a specific interface - or more simply to just 'up' the stack a specific number of frames.

If you included this in your implementation of `void Info(..)` you could access method names as

```
# get the name of the current method (i.e. Info)
new StackFrame(0, false).GetMethod().Name

# get the name of the calling method (i.e. TraceInformation)
new StackFrame(1, false).GetMethod().Name

# get the name of the parent calling method - what you are looking for 
new StackFrame(2, false).GetMethod().Name
```

Of course, you then need to reconcile when the method is called from the `ITracer` object and when it is called directly. You could also get calling objects, inspect what interfaces they implement, and record appropriate method name.

This all uses reflection so you will need to consider performance impact, however I expect that `CallerMemberName` also uses reflection / may have similar impact.